# Application of Rolle's Theorem

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Show that there holds $$\sqrt{1+x} < 1+(x/2)$$ for all $x > 0$ .

I need guidance in doing this question. Can anyone help please? I'll be thankful!

Answer (score 4):

Fix $x>0$ and let $f(t)=\sqrt{1+t}$ then by mean value theorem there's $\xi\in(0,x)$ s.t.
$$f(x)-f(0)=\sqrt{1+x}-1=xf'(\xi)=\frac{x}{2\sqrt{1+\xi}}< \frac{x}{2}\quad \text{QED} $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use [Bernoulli's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality)

Or consider the function $f(x) = 1 + \frac{x}{2} - \sqrt{1+x}$. $$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}$$ Now $f'$ is $0$  when $1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}=0 \implies x =0$. And $f''(0)> 0$ which says $f$ has a minimum at $x=0$. This says that $$1+\frac{x}{2}-\sqrt{1+x} > 0$$ which solves your problem.

Comment: sorry, i made a mistake with the title. To do this, i have to use rolle's theorem. do you know how to do rolle's theorem?

Comment: You want $>$ in the last inequality.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Edited, got confused. Now I noted that $f''$ is positive so it will be a minumum instead of a maximum. Thanks by the way

Comment: Your solution should read $f^{''}(0) > 0$ and so $x=0$ is a minimum, but this is what we want anyway since then the function is positive elsewhere implying $1+\frac{x}{2}-\sqrt{1+x}>0$ or $1+\frac{x}{2}>\sqrt{1+x}$.

Answer (score 1):

You should use rather something related to Rolle's theorem, which is Lagrange's theorem. A consequence of this is that if $f$ is differentiable and $f'>0$ over some interval $I$; then $f$ is increasing on $I$.

Let $$g(x)=1+\frac x 2 -\sqrt{1+x}$$

Note $g(0)=0$ and $g'(x)=\dfrac 1 2 -\dfrac 1 2\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}$

But $x>0\iff 1+x>1\iff \sqrt{1+x}>1$. Thus when $x>0$, $$1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}>0$$ so that $g'(x)>0$ for each $x>0$. This means $g$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$, and since $g(0)=0$, $g$ is positive over $[0,\infty)$, that is $$\sqrt{1+x}<1+\frac x 2$$

for $x>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x}$,$x>0$

By mean value theorem we have,

$\displaystyle \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(t)$ where $t\in(0,x)$

$\displaystyle \sqrt{1+x}-1=x\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+t}}\le \frac{x}{2}$,as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t}}\le 1$

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow \sqrt{1+x}\le 1+\frac{x}{2}$

Comment: One may very well first prove Rolle and then deduce MVT. The advantage to this is the proof is simpler.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff yes you are right. So I am deleting that.

Comment: I didn't say it was wrong, just that there are other options. It **is** worth remarking that MVT is intimately related to Rolle's theorem.

Comment: Yes I also think that proving Rolles from MVT is much simpler most often this is the procedure we use. So I have deleted that comment from the answer.

Comment: Just about every standard Calculus textbook proves the MVT by way of Rolle's theorem. It seems a bit overkill for this problem though.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this problem is intended to give you practice with Rolle'e Theorem but why not just square both sides:

$$\sqrt{1+x}<1+\frac{x}{2}$$

$$1+x<1+x+\frac{x^2}{4}$$ whenever $x>0$.

Comment: Yes, it is a practice to use Rolle's Theorem but I dont know how to use Rolle's Theorem...